# How to display an EPS file?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, eps

My web application currently displays PNG files. It is going to be easier if I could use an EPS file. How do I display an EPS file from InDesign on the canvas in Javascript?

Comment: its not that easy `:Đ`

Comment: if it would have been easy, I wouldn't have asked lol

Comment: [this appears to be the spec](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/5002.EPSF_Spec.pdf), write a parser for it in JS.

Comment: https://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf is the reference for it

Comment: Can you convert the file server side?

Comment: "From InDesign" *must* be a totally irrelevant specification. "EPS" is just a wrapper around a full PostScript program, and PostScript is a Turing-complete programming language. Therefore, you must write a full PostScript interpreter ... In addition, this needs you to understand various *font formats* as well as, for modern EPS files, a full PDF parser.